# Does the ban on game identification cover custom game levels?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, game-identification

I am looking for a particular level wad file from Doom II.

Is this allowed, or is it banned via the "Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone" exclusion?
I read [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1822/does-our-policy-on-recommendations-extend-to-game-mods), but didn't find the answer there.

I'm unclear as I know the game, and it's not a gameplay changing mod.

Comment: I'm... not sure there's a set policy that would cover your proposed question. However, the question would have the [same pitfalls](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) as [game identification](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4170/30115); without an audio/visual artifact to verify against, no one else can really judge the usefulness of any answer, and it becomes a guessing game.

Answer (score 10):

I would say it falls into the exact same category as other game identification questions.

Memory is inherently flawed and any question that relies on it alone for identifying a game, or mod. While a mod would be limited to a single game, and the problem space is smaller, it still suffers from the rest of the issues of game identification.

Without an artifact from the mod, I don't think this is something we can support.

Comment: My understanding is that questions asking to ID a game off memory are banned due to how inherently difficult it would be to resolve, and reliably back an answer. This would only be made harder with custom levels, which are less likely to have an internet presence as an officially published video game.